# Saving Attachment Files on the disk using Debenu PDFViewer get failed

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-generation

I used the Debenu PDFViewer in the winForm on the C# project in VS2008. I would like to save the attachment on the disk. The attachment files are saved but the return value of the method is 0 (it means failed). The saved file cannot open on Adobe Reader and the pop up message is like that

[image]

There is my code to load the pdf file and save the attachment files.

```
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            axDPVActiveX1.OpenFile(openFileDialog1.FileName);
              for (int i = 1; i <= axDPVActiveX1.DQPLEmbeddedFileCount(); i++)
            {      
              if (axDPVActiveX1.DQPLGetEmbeddedFileStrProperty(i, 5).Contains(".pdf"))
                {


                      if (axDPVActiveX1.DQPLGetEmbeddedFileContentToFile(i, @"C:\Users\userName\Desktop\Test folder\" + axDPVActiveX1.DQPLGetEmbeddedFileStrProperty(i, 5) == 1)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Done!");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Failed!");
                    }
                    MessageBox.Show(axDPVActiveX1.DQPLGetEmbeddedFileContentToString(i));
                }
            }
        }


    Would someone show me how to fix it. Thanks in advance.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have checked your code and on my side with my test files it is working as it should (appart from one missing bracket in the DQPLGetEmbeddedFileContentToFile if statement).

You can try to test in on your side using this test file:
[attachTest.pdf](https://www.dropbox.com/s/iw3iv1vw7eklul1/attachTest.pdf)

If it works then your PDF document may be malformed. If thats the case it would be helpfull if you can send me sample document thats having this issue. Thats the only way i can help you right now.

Comment: @ MatusPizur, the tested file from your works fine. I think I need to creating test file. thanks.